# In Ruby, how to return a sentence with each word reversed in place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, reverse

I want to write a method that takes a string as an argument and returns the same sentence with each word reversed in place.

example:-

```
reverse_each_word("Hello there, and how are you?")
#=> "olleH ,ereht dna woh era ?uoy"
```

I tried:

```
def reverse_each_word(string)
  array = []
  new_array=array <<string.split(" ")
  array.collect {|word| word.join(" ").reverse}
end
```

but the return is

```
["?uoy era woh dna ,ereht olleH"]
```

The whole sentence is reversed and not sure why there is `[ ]`

any help??

Comment: `"there,"` and `"you?"` are words?

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative approach, you could use [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#gsub-method) to find all words and [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#reverse-method) them:

```
str = "Hello there, and how are you?"

str.gsub(/\S+/, &:reverse)
#=> "olleH ,ereht dna woh era ?uoy"
```

`/\S+/` matches one or more (`+`) non-whitespace (`\S`) characters

Comment: `str.gsub(/[\w]*\b/, &:reverse) ` would be slightly better as it won't "flip" the punctuation around. `"olleH ereht, dna woh era uoy?"`. https://rubular.com/r/JHXKtBZe7yTZGJ

Comment: @max I'd prefer that, too. But according to the OP's example, punctuation seems to be treated as part of a word.

Answer (score 2):

```
def reverse_each_word(string)
  new_array = string.split(" ")
  new_array.collect {|word| word.reverse }.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: One possible weakness is that this converts multiple contiguous spaces to a single space.

Comment: @max Indeed, but I wanted OP to see where his mistake was so I kinda used his style.